# Can I create an arrow using background only?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am looking for a way to create an arrow using css backgrounds only.

In my case this is for a select dropdown, so cannot use pseudo elements which are not supported by select.

I am aware I could use canvas to achieve this if using backgrounds only is not possible - [Use <canvas> as a CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397334/use-canvas-as-a-css-background)

Comment: Could you tell us the style you want to achieve? Color, size, versus...

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ not real arrow but triangle....

Comment: Any possibility of colours and sizes.

Comment: Pawel - this is not relevant as it does not use backgrounds.

Comment: Basically you cannot "shape" backgrounds. You can apply, perhaps a linear gradient as a background image but then you might as well use an actual image.

Comment: I am not going to put this in an answer but what about using a font? http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Comment: Scratch that, I thought you could simply add the font awesome class to any element, but it will implement it using a pseudo class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `linear-gradient`s, if you want to use `background`.

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent), linear-gradient(-45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, black 75%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, black 75%);
  background-position: 20px 0;
  background-size: 40px 35px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If you want something similar to greater than or less than sign, use `svg`.

```html
<!--'Greater than' sign-->
<svg width="40" height="50" viewBox="0 0 42 52">
  <path d="M0,0 l40,25 l-40,25" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>

<!--'Less than' sign-->
<svg width="40" height="50" viewBox="0 0 42 52">
  <path d="M40,0 l-40,25 l40,25" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>

<!--'Greater than' sign - Thick stroke-->
<svg width="40" height="50" viewBox="0 0 42 53">
  <path d="M0,0 l40,25 l-40,25" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>

<!--'Greater than' sign - Thick stroke-->
<svg width="40" height="50" viewBox="-2 0 42 52">
  <path d="M40,0 l-40,25 l40,25" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

Also, take a look at: [Using `svg` as a `background-image`](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

Comment: Is there a way to reduce this to a set size / area within the element's background. Eg. create a 20px x 20px arrow within an element that is say 200px x 200px @chipChocolate.py

Comment: Any reason for the down-vote guys? I believe the answer is quite valid to the question asked. (*create using background only*)

Comment: If its not possible to restrict the linear-gradient background to a specific size, what would be better performance wise - to draw the arrow using canvas or load an image? 

This suggests that drawing basic shapes would have less impact on performance than loading the image - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488441/html5-canvas-performance-loading-images-vs-drawing

Comment: @chipChocolate.py - Great tips! I opted for svg encoded to base64.

Works great...

`select{
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPSc4JyBoZWlnaHQ9JzgnPjxwYXRoIGQ9J00wIDIgTDQgNiBMOCAyJyBmaWxsPSdub25lJyBzdHJva2U9J2JsYWNrJyBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9JzInIC8+PC9zdmc+)
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use the ▼   character, or

`<span class="caret"></span>`

*-- added on request*

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option default disabled="disabled" >choose ▼</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you show how would I use this within a select element?

Comment: explain what you want it to look like first.  But I guess you want something like this : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-btndropdown-dependency

Comment: Exactly, but using standard select element.